# Cannot use GetStreamSample method in python-twitter package on the cloud(ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, twitter, cloud

I tried to run some python code to harvest tweets using the twitter stream API. I am using the python-twitter package and the "getstreamsample()" method. My code works fine on my own laptop, but when I try to run it on cloud(Ubuntu), the "getstreamsample()" method seems to return None without any error message. I tried the other non-streaming methods on the cloud, like "home_timeline()", they worked fine. It seems that only the streaming one is not working. Does anybody have any idea about this?

My code is as the following:(The mongodb part works fine too)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import twitter
from pymongo import MongoClient

#Setting up Twitter API
api = twitter.Api(
 consumer_key='Xxs...1Z8',
 consumer_secret='LMegmAgtD...jKiCf',
 access_token_key='2728....aEw1',
 access_token_secret='LLZ...9cJfN71',
    sleep_on_rate_limit=True
 )



def main():

    client = MongoClient('mongodb://xxx')
    db = client.test
    test=db.test       

    for line in api.GetStreamSample(stall_warnings=True):
        if "text" in line:
            if line['lang']=='en':
                tweet={'created_at':line['created_at'],
                       'text':line['text'],                           'coordinates':line['coordinates'],'_id':line['id_str']}

                test.replace_one(tweet, tweet, True)
                print (tweet)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This code did work once but after that it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

The twitter streaming API has been experiencing problems since the attack on DYN the 21st of October. These have been reported on the twitter developer forum, and twitter staff are aware of the issue: https://twittercommunity.com/t/issues-reported-with-streams-since-10-21/76429.

As of yet, there is not a clear answer for what the cause of the problem is, but the observed behaviour is that connections to any of Twitter's streaming endpoints get closed after short periods of time, normally (although not always) without receiving any data. Sometimes the connection gets closed whilst sending the response resulting in invalid JSON.

REST endpoints seem to be working

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I finally got my code working. I am not sure it is due to the problem of twitter's streaming API. The streaming code always works on my laptop, and only worked several times on the cloud. It seems the streaming API has different limits to these two IP addresses. So I just left the code running on the cloud when I found it worked.